# CSS3 transformations values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit

So I am building a gallery in which I zoom in and out an image with Bounce.js, which uses css3 animations (specifically matrix3d transformations) to do the job. Once the image finishes zooming in/out, I actually wanna remove the animation and set the final css property to the element itself, so I can then do things, like moving it around, with its real properties and no the old ones (the ones before the object animation, which stayed there since the script does not change them).

So with a few words, **how can I get how an object is actually looking after an animation?** I've tried to guess it myself, calculating the final state given the transformation type and rest of values, but is causing me headache and I do not know what to do.

Everything I've tried does not work well and I'd be much easier to get the values right off without trying to calculate them.

Note I would also like to be able to get `top/bottom` and `left/right` values since the element is placed `absolute`ly and that really matters to me.

Here is the animation:

```
@keyframes animation { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.14531, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.14531, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.14531, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.14531, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  25% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  37.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.20818, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.20818, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.20818, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.20818, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.20447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.20447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.20447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.20447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  62.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.20122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.20122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.20122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.20122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  75% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  87.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.19982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.19982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.19982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.19982, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}
```

It seems to be easy to calculate since it is just to multiply by 1.2, but since it is `absolute`ly positioned, the top and left values are very hard to find out after the animation.

Comment: [see this question from a popular SO user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331988/freeze-keyframe-animation-for-debugging)

Comment: @jbutler483 thank you that might help

Comment: @jbutler483 their example is not working for me. I don't know how to make it work

Comment: codepen works fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Safari last version on Mac OS X. I mean, I can't get anything with that. How can I get each element's properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `$("#yourelement").position()` to get the current position of the element.

It worked for me, once I tried your animation. It also provides negative values if the element offset is out of the screen.

It returns an object with two values, top and left.